# R: How can I change the color of lines in a forest plot based on criteria within my original data set?

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am trying to change the color of the confidence interval lines in my forestplot based on pvalue to indicate statistical significance based on a 95% CI. I have tried ifelse statements within fpColors, among other things but I've not been successful yet.

These are the colors I want:

1 = SRR<1 with pvalue<=0.05 = green,

2 = SRR>1 with pvalue<=0.05 = red,

3 = otherwise color = grey

**This is my code:**

```
   tabletext <- cbind(c("name","\n",data1$name), 
               c("Observed","\n",data1$Count), 
               c("Predicted","\n",data1$Predicted), 
               c("SRR","\n",data1$SRR),
               c("P value","\n",data1$pval) )

      png(file.path("C:/R Work Folder\\forestplot4"), width =960 ,height=1584)
    forestplot(labeltext=tabletext, graph.pos=7,
       mean=c(NA,NA,data1$SIR),
       lower=c(NA,NA,data1$CIlow), upper=c(NA,NA,data1$CIhigh),
       title="Standardized Ratio",
       xlab="  <--- Better--- ---Worse--->",
       #hrzl_lines= gpar(odd, lwd=1, col="#99999922"), 
       txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label=gpar(cex=1.25),
                      ticks=gpar(cex=1.1),
                      xlab=gpar(cex = 1.2),
                      title=gpar(cex = 1.2)),
       col=fpColors( box="black",zero="gray50", lines="black"), 
       zero=1, cex=0.9, lineheight = "auto", boxsize=0.4, 
       colgap=unit(5,"mm"), lwd.ci=2, ci.vertices=TRUE, ci.vertices.height = 0.4)
  dev.off()
```

I found an example of another way to do this where someone coded a function for color.. but I can't get this to work within fpColors and don't want a colorRamp, I just want green and red and grey lines.

```
fn<-local({
    i=0
    no_lines<-sum(!is.na(data1$SIR))
    bclrs=colorRampPalette(colors=c("black"))(no_lines)
    lclrs=colorRampPalette(colors=c("green", "red"))(no_lines)

function(...,clr.line, clr.marker){
  i<<-i+1
  fpDrawNormalCI(...,clr.line=lclrs[i],clr.marker=bclrs[i])}
})


  forestplot(labeltext=tabletext, fn.ci_norm=fn,
       data1, new_page=TRUE,
       is.summary=c(TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE,94)),
       clip=c(0.1,2.5),
       col=fpColors(summary="black"))
```

I have also tried this to see if I could get the first 5 plots to change to red, and leave the rest black.. but everything changed to red.

```
  col=fpColors( lines =c(rep('red', 5),'black')),
```

Comment: I've been working on this, and I feel like I'm getting closer but it still won't work.    cols <- fpColors(lines=c("red", "green", "grey")[match(data1$icon, c("1", "2", "3"))]). But when I replace col=fpColors with col=cols, my plot doesn't have lines.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html this has been a great resource, please let me know if I'm missing something.